# How do I go about safely taking a screenshot of a website that I know is infected with malware?

Tags: malware, safe-browsing

**Background:**

One of my clients' websites has become a malware infested hotbed.

Disposing of the malware has proven difficult and time consuming, and, in the meantime, we still have had to do work on the site.

For now, we went to some trouble to do our work - creating a disposable VM to just run a web browser, so we can see what the site looks like for the designers' work, for example.

I'm wondering if there's an easier (and faster) way to get an idea what the design of the site looks like. Not everyone on the project is tech savvy enough to be trusted with, for example, properly handling switching VMs.

**Question:**

Is there a method for safely seeing what a malware infested website looks like (for example, a service which will browse the site for me and send a screenshot), one which ideally is easy and simple enough to use that I can trust our non-tech-savvy designers to user?

Answer (score 3):

You might take at look at [Internet Archive: Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php) to see if the site has been archived.

Comment: That's a good idea, however, the site has not been archived, and I doubt that archiving iterations are fast enough to be reliably current. Also, google doesn't have a cached version of it.

Answer (score 2):

If a screenshot is all you need, there are several online browser simulators, such as [Net Renderer](http://netrenderer.com/)  (which will run any inputted web URL in a given version of Internet Explorer and then supply a screenshot). You might also try BrowserStack, which requires an account, and is not free, but does have a free trial period, and offers more than Internet Exploder.

You could also try running a browser in [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/), which is simpler to set up and use than a VM (you just install it, and then use the windows right-click menu to launch any program in a sandbox of your choosing). However, it isn't free for commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if exist a standalone tool to parse a website for malwares, but I think this can help you, it's a google tool that you can you with a request and they will send you a response.
Follow the link:
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168328

Hope it helped.